# print data into text file

Tags: c

I want to print some values into the text file which contains some data. The problem is that I want to print data at the end of each line after the data that is already in text file.

Here is my text file:

```
100 1 
120 2
160 6
200 7
300 6
```

Source:

```
for(i=0; i<5; i++){
    fseek(txt, 2, SEEK_SET);
    fprintf(txt," %d\n",num[m]);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only way to do that in C:

1. read in every line
2. append the data you want to the end of the line, or just rewrite the whole line
3. and write the line to a new file.

You could do that using sed/awk.

Comment: @alk Sorry, I mean a new file

Answer (score 0):

use another file..copy each line of original file alternatively with your "new" file...after you are done remove the original file and rename it to the original file's name

while(fread())
{
   copy to temp file.
&  add the new line to the temp file
}

remove(original);
rename(temp,original);

Comment: i mean copy 1 line..and add the desired line..till you are done.